# Why is Vertx server unable to communicate with node server hosted via WSL? (MWE provided)

Tags: node.js, typescript, http, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vert.x

My Vertx backend server is unable to send HTTP (GET) requests to a node server (typescript) running on the same machine via WSL. However, via Postman I am able to send HTTP (GET) requests to the node server.

**I will provide a minimal, workable example:**

First of all, localhost hosts the node server with following **config**:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.12",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^15.14.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
```

**index.ts**:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8081

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("standard route called");
    res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

The backend server is a Vertx server (Vertx 4.0.2) that uses a Vertx Web Client to send a HTTP GET-request to "localhost:8081/":

```
package org.example

import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx
import io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.Router
import io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.client.WebClient

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
    val router = Router.router(vertx)

    val webClient = WebClient.create(vertx)

    webClient.get(8081, "localhost", "/").rxSend().subscribe { result ->
        println(result.statusMessage())
    }

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router).listen(8080)


}
```

When starting the vertx server (and sending the HTTP GET) the following error occurs:

> Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException:
> Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:8081
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further
> information   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
> at
> io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:330)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:702)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
> at
> io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)     at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
> at
> io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

**It is important to note** that the actual node server is hosted via WSL because it uses libraries only usable in Linux. When the node server is hosted via Windows (localhost), the Vertx server has access. How come the Vertx server cannot access the local node server hosted via WSL? And what do I need to do in order for this to be possible?

Comment: You code seems fine, the issue is most probably the WSL. From the log it seems that your `localhost` is not resolved correctly. Could you try "127.0.0.1" instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, both "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" give the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can access a WSL service that is hosted locally on Windows via the IPv6 '::1'.